# Service keeps crashing before application opens

Tags: android, android-service

I am having trouble starting a `Service`. It crashes before the application even starts.

```
      Intent repSer = new Intent(this,repService.class);

      startService(repSer);
```

this is the `Service` itself.:

```
public class repService extends Service {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    while(true){
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                    // do something

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();  
    }   
}
}
```

perhaps this is wrong? 
my manifest entry:

```
    <service android:name = ".repService"/>  
  </application>
```

Comment: Do you have any LOGCAT entries you could look at (or paste) to debug?

Comment: need to find a video or tutorial on logcat... forgive me i am only starting and dont yet understand the logcat very well. i just know how to post messages : Log.d(String tag,String msg);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just constantly looping through the while and starting new Threads with timers inside. You're probably overloading with Threads. As fast as the while() statement can loop you're creating another Thread and starting it.

Comment: even if i take the while out my application still crashes before it even opens.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to execute this code you will surely get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`
Since the loop is never going to break.

That is the main reason your application is crashing.

Also make sure you have defined `<service android:name=".repService" />` in manifest

Your manifest should look something like following

[image]

Comment: even if i take out and leave the service with just onbind and oncreate application still crashes before it opens...

Comment: its like u read my mind. just posted it. seems to be identical